# Select a certain value from a pandas dense rank dataframe

Tags: pandas, transform, dense-rank

I have a pandas dataframe with dense rank matrix and want to select all the cells that have 2. And then transform it to results dataframe like below. I am looping through each column and row with just for-loop but is there a better way?

df looks like

```
    A   B   C  ........ x 2000 columns 
AA  1   3   2
BB  2   1   3
CC  2   2   1
 .
 .
 .
 x
2000 rows
```

results_df to be like

```
    Col1  Col2
0   A     BB
1   A     CC
2   B     CC
3   C     AA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method.

```
rows, cols = np.nonzero((df==2).values)

results_df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'Col1':[df.columns[c] for c in cols], 
    'Col2':[df.index[r] for r in rows]
}).sort('Col1').reset_index(drop=True)
```

For example:

```
In [88]: df
Out[88]: 
    A  B  C
AA  1  3  2
BB  2  1  3
CC  2  2  1

In [89]: pandas.DataFrame({'Col1':[df.columns[c] for c in cols], 'Col2':[df.index[r] for r in rows]}).sort('Col1').reset_index(drop=True)
Out[89]: 
  Col1 Col2
0    A   BB
1    A   CC
2    B   CC
3    C   AA
```

Comment: Ah nice. Did not know we can do that